# not getting response from Mixpanel

Tags: php, api

I am using Mixpanel class object.

```
$mp   = Mixpanel::getInstance("my_token");  
$data = $mp->track("My Event");
echo "<pre>"; 
print_r($data);
$data is blank!
```

Comment: is it showing any error?

Comment: No, i am getting blank screen.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked in live view if you can see the event "My Event" being tracked? If you can see the events being tracked while executing the above code then it is working fine. You donot need to assign the mixpanel event to another variable. Just do: `$mp->track("My Event");`